# Azure function 5 and EF Core 5 Could not load file or assembly > Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
> Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

I am getting above error when running the tests in azure devops pipeline but not when running it local. Everything works locally fine.

I believe the error happens when the base class try to initialize DB Context using EF Core 5 at line 15.

[image]

Code stack:

**Azure function isolated enabled .Net 5**

**EF Core 5**

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening? Below is the screenshot of the packages referenced in the test project.

[image]

Comment: They should be the same version: Change Abstractions to 5.0.2

Comment: Even after changing EF Core, Dependency and Abstraction to 5 .0.0, I am getting the same error

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: @singhh-msft No. I have to downgrade everything it to 3.1. Cant take risk of going to production with the .Net 5

Comment: Are there more issues? Or only this is not resolved yet?

Answer (score -1):

There can be two reasons for this, AFAIK:

- Make sure you have all Nuget packages compatible to each other in the porject. Check if `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` has the version which is compatible to all other Nuget packages in the project. One way to find dependencies is in the Nuget Package Manager:

  [image]
- Make sure these packages are included in the `.csproj` file of the project:

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.1" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.4">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and downgrading the Worker package doesn't resolve the issue.